# matplotlib draw showing nothing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using python's matplotlib to do some contours using contour and contourf functions. They all work fine when using show, but when I try to use draw() inside a method, I get the matplotlib window but not graph. The show() call will be done much later on the code and in a different method, and I would like to show one graph at the moment when it's done with draw(), not having to wait until the much later show(). What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC ,You should be able call fig.show() multiple times.  Also, check out using ipython (`ipython -pylab`) and http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/shell.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I'm not using an interactive environment - this is a simulation in a script. And the problem with calling show several times is that show() is blocking, and I need that the program keeps running after displaying the graph without user intervention.

Comment: Ah, right.  Not sure, then.  random thought:  if you can't do this with the plotting facilities, you could always export the graph to an image file and pass that around

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. I'm trying to avoid exactly that - I need a graph to decide if the results will be saved or not.

Answer (score 7):

Have you turned interactive mode on using `ion()`?  The following works for me on OSX, using the Tk backend and running from the shell's command line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
for i in range(10):
    plt.plot([i], [i], 'o')
    plt.draw()
raw_input("done >>")
```

That is, as it does each loop, you see the plot change (i.e., it gets redrawn) as each point is added.  Here, btw, if I instead call `plt.ioff()`, I don't see the figure or any updates.

Comment: @andi: I think that something is probably setup incorrectly with your environment.  I just ran this again to check it and it still works for me, but now, 4+ years later using a different computer, versions, environment, etc.  If you can't get it to work, I suggest asking a separate question with more details (eg, does plt.ion() work for you in other cases, what versions are you using, etc).

Comment: You are absolutly right! Reinstalled anaconda and it works perfectly. Sorry about that.