# Plot sine wave from serial data and plotting float values

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, floating-point, trigonometry

```
import sys
import serial
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from collections import deque

port = "COM11"
baud = 9600
timeout=1

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = port
ser.baudrate = baud
ser.timeout = timeout


a1 = deque([0.0]*100)
#ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 100), ylim=(0, 1000))



line, = plt.plot(a1)
plt.ion()
plt.ylim([0,1000])

try:
  ser.open()
except:
  sys.stderr.write("Error opening serial port %s\n" % (ser.portstr) )
  sys.exit(1)

#ser.setRtsCts(0)

while 1:
     # Read from serial port, blocking
     data = ser.read(1)

     # If there is more than 1 byte, read the rest
     n = ser.inWaiting()
     data = data + ser.read(n)
     #sys.stdout.write(data)
     print(a1)

     a1.appendleft((data))
     datatoplot = a1.pop()
     line.set_ydata(a1)
     plt.draw()
```

I am getting a time domain plot of serial data but I want to convert data I am receiving from serial port into a sine wave and then perform analysis on that.Is there anything that can be done?
Thanks

One more question:
I wanted to plot float values so I multiplied the data with 0.000714285714 and then tried for plot but I get this error. 
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\time and frequency domain.py", line 70, in 
            a1.appendleft(float(data*0.000714285714))
        TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
Please look into this question, it is even more important than the first one.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by converting it into a sine wave? Do you mean a frequency analysis of the signal (FFT or the like) or something else? What shape is the signal you receive? Could you append a plot for clarity?

Comment: I want to do fft of signal but since I not getting some random numbers I am not able to analyze this so I thought of converting this into sine wave and then go for fft. Also I tried sending the image of plot but since I had some less points so I could not send the image.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by converting it into a sine wave, maybe I'm missing something here? As for the new question, could you try `a1.appendleft(float(data) * 0.000714285714)` and see if that works? Could you also provide a example print of the variable `data` after `data = ser.read(1)` and again after `data = data + ser.read(n)` plase, just so we can see what kind of data we're working with and what happens to it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am able to plot for float values.Regarding my first question,I want to send sine wave using function generator to msp430f5438a and I want to plot sine wave at the receiver side but since I am using adc12 to send my values so they are in the range of 0 to 255 and I get some random values but I want to plot sine wave for which my values should be in the range of -1 to 1. Can I do this using python?

Comment: The short answer is that, yes you can. That's not a very helpful answer, though... If I understand you correctly, and each sample is represented by one byte send from adc12, then what you would need to do is something like `data = (float(data) - 128) / 128.0` to get the right span for your values. If that is how it works, I think the reason behind your randomness may be `data = data + ser.read(n)`, which seems to add datapoints to your first read data, effectively destroying it through over-flow etc. What happens if you simply remove that line? Does your signal look better then?

Comment: Other things that may be causing problems are too high or too low gain on your sinewave. Both of these may be worth checking out. Also see this discussion, which concerns a slightly different problem, but where it seems they've managed to get the reading right at least: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22495861/plotting-serial-data-in-python-how-to-pause-matplotlib-figure?rq=1